# jQuery ignored in ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery and Ajax to populate a select. Now I'm trying to do that in my success callback, But it's being ignored

#### The weird part is that my console.log('test'); is working in my success callback, But my DOM manipulation isn't. And my DOM manipulation is working outside of the success callback.

seems like magic to me. Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// This is working
//$('select[name="service"]').append('<option selected="selected" value="1">Test</option>');

$('select[name="region"]').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/updateServices.php",
        data: "region=" + $(this).val(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            // this is also working
            console.log('test');
            // This is being ignored
            $('select[name="service"]').append('<option selected="selected" value="1">Test</option>');

        }
    });
});
```

});

## EDIT

It seems like selectize.js is causing the issue. I'm gonna look into why selectize.js is causing this.

Comment: check: `alert($('select[name="service"]').length)`  But following your posted code, there is no reason for that so obviously you didn't post all relevant code

Comment: This is returning 1. And it's working from inside the success callback, and outside

Comment: Then i don't see why your code wouldn't work. Aren't you removing option in code later?

Comment: Could you post you DOM code please?

Comment: Nope.. I really don't understand it either..

Comment: Now try to replicate your issue online to let us check

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, and it's working because i'm not using the success callback? JsFiddle can't replicate db and ajax can it?

Comment: @MiguelStevens sure it can. Post relevant code in jsfiddle, i'll try to fix it. But anyway, your issue doesn't come from your posted code. PS: just saw your edit about selectize.js, sure this could explain it

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It seems that selectize has a different approach of populating the select's.. A more difficult approach that's for sure :)

Comment: its $('select[name=service]') and not: $('select[name="service"]')

Answer (score 0):

i would share my history with select plugin:
Some select plugin such as SelectBox requires you do destroy the jquery object before populating the select again or changing anything, even selectedIndex THAT you need to declare the select as the select-plugin again
for example (with selectBox, but works the same on others)

```
$("#MySelect").selectBox('destroy')
$("#MySelect").append("<option>New Option </option>");
$("#MySelect").selectBox()
```

also, make sure when debugging, that `$('select[name="service"]')` returns the desired select and not an empty object, most issues are resolved when in debug mode (dont use debug mode? use Chrome Developer tools under Source tab).